# Material Dialog not open after clicking on marker in ngx-leaflet

Tags: angular, leaflet, typeerror, ngx-leaflet, material-dialog

I'm using `ngx-leaflet` and `ngx-leaflet-draw` for displaying leaflet map. I can display a marker on the map from the toolbar-marker-icon. I want to display a Material Dialog Component when I click on the marker. I can display marker coordinate on the console when I click on the marker. the code is

```js
public onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
      const type = (e as any).layerType,
        layer = (e as any).layer;

      if (type === 'marker') {
        const markerCoordinates = layer._latlng;
        layer.on('click', () => {
          console.log(markerCoordinates); // works properly
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Then I try to modify the code for displaying Material Dialog Component but get error

```js
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MaterialDialogComponent } from './m-dialog.component';
...
...
export class NgxLeafletComponent {
  dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MaterialDialogComponent>;

  public constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  public onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
      map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
        const type = (e as any).layerType,
          layer = (e as any).layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
          const markerCoordinates = layer._latlng;
          layer.on('click', () => {
            console.log(markerCoordinates); 
            this.zone.run(() => this.onClickMarker()); //error
          });
        }
      });
    }

  onClickMarker() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MaterialDialogComponent);
  }
 }
```

the error output: [image: Error Console output]

I also try this without `zone.run()` method, directly `dialog.open()` method but again caught error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

**NOTE:** *when I try this outside `onMapReady()` method and  without `ngx-leaflet` it works totally fine.*

Comment: basically map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
**any external function/method aren't called  here. what is the solution?**
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem and solved it. here I used regular function() on `map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {...}` which is not allowed another function to call. So it need to arrow function to call another method/function in it.

```js
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MaterialDialogComponent } from './m-dialog.component';
...
...
export class NgxLeafletComponent {
  dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MaterialDialogComponent>;

  public constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  public onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
      map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e) => {
        const type = (e as any).layerType,
          layer = (e as any).layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
          const markerCoordinates = layer._latlng;
          layer.on('click', () => {
            console.log(markerCoordinates); 
            this.zone.run(() => this.onClickMarker()); //error
          });
        }
      });
    }

  onClickMarker() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MaterialDialogComponent);
  }
 }
```